# how to set an adobe Air application initial window to full screen

Tags: air

I have an  air app created from one of Adobe's Examples using javascript / HTML.  Is it possible to change the descriptor file so the application launches full screen or maximized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you could call the maximize(); function in the application creation Complete function.

Comment: This one did the trick.   I was looking for something to put inside `<initialWindow>` which is probably why my searches were comming up empty = ).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps (from here: http://www.kerkness.ca/how-to-launch-an-adobe-air-windowedapplication-in-full-screen-mode/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" applicationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function init():void
        {
            systemManager.stage.displayState=flash.display.StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE
        }
    ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.
onCreationComplete - call this method of the main application creation complete

```
private function onCreationComplete():void{
var current:Screen;
var scrArray:Array = Screen.screens;
var screens:Array = Screen.getScreensForRectangle(stage.nativeWindow.bounds);
(screens.length > 0) ? current = screens[0] : current = Screen.mainScreen;
this.width = current .bounds.width ;
this.height = current .bounds.height;
this.nativeWindow.x = 0;
this.nativeWindow.y = 0;
}
```